# BJT transistor junctions: base-collector

Tags: bjt, emitter-follower

I've been playing with voltage swings in a basic emitter-follower circuit.  If I swing the input too large in the negative cycle, the base-emitter junction is reverse-biased and the transister goes into cutoff mode.  I can see the clipping in the output and this makes sense to me.  With the collector, however, I've noticed that I can swing higher and not see symmetrcial clipping.  Eventually I do see the clipping.

Is there a rule of thumb, like with the base-emitter junction, for managing base-collector junction?  May I use VC-VB=0.6/0.7 V for this relationship too?

Comment: Take a look at my emitter-follower answer - it shows the assumptions made for that circuit.  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/emitter-follower-output/8659#8659

Comment: How poor my memory is!  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drive the base positive enough (assuming an NPN) what happens is the transistor 'saturates', and the collector voltage will dip to just a couple tenths above the emitter. In this mode, the base-collector junction is actually forward biased, instead of reverse biased as is usually the case.

Answer (score 1):

BJT is usually asymmetrical.

There is no rules AFAIK, they all different there - so you need to test each type you need.